Where to store requests to a server with the FSD architecture?
I have some requests: sign-in, sign-up, log-out and so on. And I use each of them once. It works I just want to know if I'm breaking the rules of FSD.
Now I have such structure:
--widgets
    --AuthForms
        --api
            --signIn
            --signUp
        --lib
        --store
        --ui

Is it correct?
